# GTK# TreeView and StoreList won''t show data

Tags: c#, mono, treeview, gtk#

My goal is to query table and add it to ListView. I only get an empty ListView with column names and errors. I used the tutorial, but it doesn't help. I realized that empty rows are added because I can click on them.

```
        using (MySqlConnection connect = new MySqlConnection(connectionString))
        {
            connect.Open();

            // QUERY GENERATION

            mySqlCommand = new MySqlCommand(query, connect);

            // QUERY PARAMETERS ADDED

            ListStore store = new Gtk.ListStore(typeof(string[]));

            for (int i = 0; i < tempselect.Length; i++) {
                _treeView.AppendColumn(tempselect[i], new Gtk.CellRendererText(), "text");
            }

            MySqlDataReader reader = mySqlCommand.ExecuteReader();

            while (reader.Read())
            {
                store.AppendValues(reader);
            }
            reader.Close();

            _treeView.Model = store;

            connect.Close();
        }
```

There are no errors. The application just doesn't show data. There are data in the table.
I'm trying to fix this for a whole day. Nothing works.

Thank you.

Comment: I even tried adding one column and one string to the TreeView, the result is the same .... EMPTY !

Comment: I am considering of abandoning CSharp development for Linux. WAY TOO MANY PROBLEMS AND BUGS. I'm still at the beginning of development, its better now than later. When the application gets big, its going to be a bigger problem.

Comment: it's a bug in your code, not in Linux, Mono, or Gtk+

Comment: Same here. It could be a bug in gtk >= 3.10

Answer (score 1):

I have no idea what tempSelect is based on the code that you pasted...

I would recommend trying this in your loop:

```
var column = new TreeViewColumn ();
column.Title = "Column Name";
column.Clickable = false;

var renderer = new CellRendererText ();
column.PackStart (renderer, true);

column.AddAttribute (renderer, "text", 0);
_treeView.AppendColumn (column);
```

I suspect that your problem is that you just need to pass a 0 as your last argument to the AppendColumn() method that you are calling. This value is needed to specify which column the text resides in.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. There is very little help on the web for Mono and GTK#. The code you provided does not help. I tried bunch of solutions none of them worked.
The code I use in my application is written using WinForms, and it worked fine there. On Mono there was a problem with the controls, so I decided to rewrite for GTK#, while the rest of the code stayed the same. Today I realized that there are problems where I didn't expect them (with  methods that are equivalent to .NET). Fortunately I am in the early stages of development, so I will just jump to Java. Thank you for the reply.

Comment: You don't want to add the reader to the treeview, you probably want to add the value. This probably explains why it's not working. The text renderer has no idea how to render a MySqlDataReader object.

Comment: This also looks wrong: new Gtk.ListStore(typeof(string[]));  -- how do you expect a text renderer to render an array of strings? what you want is: new Gtk.ListStore(typeof(string)); and then serialize the data you read from the MySql database into a string for the text renderer to render.

Comment: Yes, that is an error which I made after rewriting some of the code. Later I fixed it. The result is the same... it wont work. I also changed the array of objects to array of string, that doesn't help either.

Comment: Yea, because you used an *array*, it has to be a single string.

Comment: If you want to display multiple columns of strings, you need to use: new ListStore (typeof (string), typeof (string), typeof (string), ...);